Customized distribution fitting
I have a sample of continuous surgery durations and want to fit a distribution to this sample to generate random numbers accordingly. Using the scipy library in Python, I can fit various distributions, but the resulting distributions often do not fit well according to the results of goodness-of-fit and K-S tests.
I'm exploring if there are any machine learning algorithms that could help me fit a customized distribution, provide an interval of lower and upper bounds similar to conformal predictive models, or offer other relevant solutions.
Note: I've already developed a predictive model that gives personalized surgery duration prediction for each patient. Instead of fitting a general distribution to the entire sample, I am considering whether a machine learning approach could provide personalized distribution sets for each patient in the sample. The reason is that I believe I can utilize other information I have available for each patient (e.g., age, health status, type of procedure, priority) so I can create a more accurate uncertainty set for the patient.
Can you please name some good potential options with references for me to read about their use cases and implementations?

How do you figure the SSE is high? Also, why shouldn't the SSE be high? (SSE of what?)

Great questions. Perhaps I should have said that goodness-of-fit or K-S tests result indicate there is not a good fit.

What does that have to do with the SSE?

I revised my post with goodness-of-fit or K-S tests to prevent any confusion. Thx.

This and this show why formal testing of your distribution fit might not be as useful as you probably hope.

How many observations do you have? Could you just use the empirical cumulative distribution?

Sounds like you're demanding nearly perfect density fitting (via K-S 1-d distribution test) to the entire training data set or clustered version of them, you don't worry about overfitting for your ML training stage?

I stand by what I wrote here about the Princess and the Pea.
You pretty much know that whatever distribution you fit will be at least a little bit incorrect. Then you ask the hypothesis test if that is the correct distribution. Lo-and-behold, the math says that, no, the posited distribution is not totally correct. The math is especially likely to give such an answer when you have a large sample size. For instance, the KS test you are using is able to reliably reject equality of $N(0, 1)$ and $N(0.05, 1)$, detecting the difference in $851$ of $1000$ simulated attempts for a power of $85.1\%$. In fairness to the KS test, the null hypothesis is false and the alternative true, so each of these rejections is correct. However, look at how similar the two densities are.

I cannot visually distinguish these two densities. Despite the math of the KS test being able to (correctly) tell that the two are different, this difference is extremely small.
Does that difference matter? To the Princess, she (correctly) felt the pea under the mattress, so the slight deviation did matter. To the Prince's other dates, they all slept fine, so that slight difference did not matter. Thus, it is a matter of assessing what kind of deviation from the theoretical distribution you fit matters for your work, and KS-testing distribution fits is not very helpful for such a task.
(This even skips over the fact that KS-testing estimated distributions is a misguided practice.)
set.seed(2024)
N <- 10000
R <- 1000

ps <- rep(NA, R)
for (i in 1:R){
  
  x <- rnorm(N, 0, 1)
  y <- rnorm(N, 0.05, 1)
  
  ps[i] <- ks.test(x, y)$p.value
  
  time_now <- Sys.time()
  if (i < 10 | Sys.time() - printout_time > 7){
    print(paste(
      i/R*100, "% complete", sep = ""
    ))
    printout_time <- Sys.time()
  }
  
}
ecdf(ps)(0.05) # Over 80% power

library(ggplot2)

s <- seq(-2, 2, 0.1)
y1 <- dnorm(s, 0, 1)
y2 <- dnorm(s, 0.01, 1)

d1 <- data.frame(
  X = s,
  PDF = y1,
  Distribution = "N(0, 1)"
)
d2 <- data.frame(
  X = s,
  PDF = y2,
  Distribution = "N(0.01, 1)"
)
d <- rbind(d1, d2)
ggplot(d, aes(x = X, y = PDF, col = Distribution)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")


What it sounds like you want to do is some kind of regression, machine learning, or predictive modeling. My recommendation is to think about the problem that way and then come back here to post a new question about how to improve your modeling by using the additional information like age. That's really what regression is about, using variables besides the one you aim to predict in order to improve your predictions.
